# Can we add new attribute in a custom module

Tags: magento-1.9

Can we add a new attribute in custom module?
I have created one module, I want to know that, how to add a new attribute in this custom module? 
if it is possible, than how can do it?

Comment: For product check this https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-product-attribute-programmatically.html

Comment: For customer check this https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html

Comment: For category check this http://inchoo.net/magento-2/add-category-attribute-magento-2/

Comment: But, how can display in custom module

Comment: For which entity you want to add an attribute?

Comment: i have create grid field in custom module, in that module i have to add this attribute

Comment: Yes i got that but for which entity like for customer or product or category?

Comment: sorry i do not create any entity, that you have mention it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57036/discussion-between-rushikesh-solanki-and-kingshuk-deb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention that whether you want to create a **customer attribute** or **product attribute**.

So that I am giving you the both code so that you can use as your requirement.

**For Customer Attribute** :

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "your_attribute_code",  array(
"type"     => "varchar",
"backend"  => "",
"label"    => "your_attribute_label",
"input"    => "text",
"source"   => "",
"visible"  => true,
"required" => false,
"default" => "",
"frontend" => "",
"unique"     => false,
"note"       => ""

));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "attribute_code");

$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
    ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
    ->setData("is_system", 0)
    ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
    ->setData("is_visible", 1)
    ->setData("sort_order", 100)
    ;

$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Use this code to your **sql** folder.

**For Product Attribute** :

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'your_attribute_code', array(
  'type'              => 'int',
  'backend'           => '',
  'frontend'          => '',
  'label'             => 'your_attribute_label',
  'input'             => 'text',
  'class'             => '',
  'source'            => '',
  'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
  'visible'           => true,
  'required'          => false,
  'user_defined'      => false,
  'default'           => '',
  'searchable'        => false,
  'filterable'        => false,
  'comparable'        => false,
  'visible_on_front'  => false,
  'unique'            => false,
  'apply_to'          => '',
  'is_configurable'   => false
));

 $installer->endSetup();
```

If you have any query feel free to comment.